# Flickering screen and off-set screen after second boot in Wubi

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I had this problem before with Fedora and solved it by deleting random lines in the GRUB2 launch commands.

This time I decided to use the Wubi install of Ubuntu. First boot was fine, but the second caused a massive amount of flickering and the screen was offset so high up I can only see about 5px of the bottom.

I tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but with the offset I have no idea what I'm typing.

I'm fairly certain `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver.xorg` or `nomodeset` are the way to go. But how?

Graphics card is Radeon 6000HD Series.

Comment: Edit your question and provide more information.

Comment: Such as? I added my graphics card.

Comment: such as some screenshots

Comment: This shows how to use nomodeset: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  After that go to `additional-drivers` to see if there is an available graphics drivers.

Comment: @EliahKagan, so what if they were long complex names?

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy Long and complex is *not* code or commands.

Comment: Got it! Can I show them in _italic_ ? just I was wondering how to make them specific ;) thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy Putting make/model names is italics is less bad than putting them in code, but this is virtually never helpful either. Most words in a make/model name are usually capitalized, and those that are not are usually not confused with the surrounding prose (because if not capitalized, they usually don't resemble English words at all). When the capitalization of a make/model name is wrong (and sometimes you'll have to check to be sure), you can correct that. But it's vanishingly rare that any special formatting would be helpful. Often, you should remove italics from these names.